# Jhipster and debugging angular js

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea, jhipster

I've built the jhipster sample application. I am quite new to angular so this may be a silly question, but how do I debug the angular javascript (ex. app.js).  I am using Intellij Idea Ultimate 14.0.2 on Windows. I installed the JB plugin for browser debug in chrome and of course enabled debugging. Still I can't get the editor to stop on break points. Hummm frustrating...if anyone has an idea I would greatly appreciate their wisdom.

Comment: An alternative idea is to debug right from Chrome. Open the developer tools and go to the sources tab. Find "app.js" and start placing debug points. Once done, refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a plugin for chrome and special configuration setting for the IDEA](http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-debug-angularjs-with-intellij/)

```
1. Install the JetBrains IDE Support extension for Chrome
2. Create a new JavaScript Debug configuration on Intellij
3. Configure your JavaScript debug configuration
4. Debug your JavaScript Debug Configuration
```